# Failing to build a node.js plugin that references the libjpeg library

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, libjpeg

I have copied the libjpeg library into the 'c' directory where I am keeping the C and C++ source code for my node.js application.

I have used the binding.gyp file to point to the C++ file, and it has built successfully. However, when I add the line

```
#include "libjpeg-master/jpeglib.h"
```

I get the error message

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jconfig.h': No such file or directory [...]
```

I am attempting to build the libjpeg library alongside the node.js code, rather than first building libjpeg using the build configuration there.

How should I go about solving this. If the answer is to use the build configuration from libjpeg, how can I get that to work when building a node.js plugin?

I am currently developing this on Windows but I want to get this working properly for all platforms.